# Multiple Github accounts based on user name instead of host

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I saw the suggestion to work with multiple Github accounts is to create a SSH config with multiple entries like so:

```
Host aliasUser1
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user1

Host aliasUser2
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user2
```

This will allow me to run commands like so:

```
git clone aliasUser1:user1/repo.git
git clone aliasUser2:user2/repo.git
```

But I prefer to have a configuration that will allow me to run the commands as usual and make the differentiation based on the org/ user name, meaning:
git clone git@github.com:user1/repo.git -> will use user1 key
git clone git@github.com:user2/repo.git -> will use user2 key

is this configuration possible?

I'm not sure what to try currently

Comment: That's not possible, because `ssh` doesn't know anything about the remote repository path you're trying to clone. It only knows you're trying to connect to host `github.com` as user `git`. Since you only have access to the remote user and hostname, those are the only two things you can use to make ssh configuration decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, you have to do a little finagling. Git's got a general-enough url rewriting config, `url.<realprefix>.insteadof`.

```
git config url.workme:user1/.insteadof git@github.com:user1/
```

and from then on Git will rewrite the `git@github.com:user1/` prefix to `workme:user1/` and then recognize the result as (still) using ssh; you need to configure your ssh to put the real connection data back:

```
host workme
  hostname github.com
  user git
  identityfile ~/.ssh/user1.pub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it seems I still need to create some kind of logic so that each user will be rewritten with its own URL.

I have just found a post with an include statement here:
https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

implemented it, seems like it is working.

Comment: @WindowSSOF Yes, clearly the idea is to do this twice, once for user1, and once for user2. And again for any other you need.